# UITabbar image moving up down

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, ios12

My UITababarController image moving up down when I am coming back from any controller back to UITabbarController.

You can check the following the link for the video:-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M06Uzik0qwiMJr8k0PxwoFVm4GfpGyXL/view?usp=sharing

Screens sizes (4.7) having this issue

Comment: Your drive link requires a permission to access. If they are images, you can directly upload here.

Comment: Dinesh Raja can't take a screenshot as I need to show the exact problem... its open

Comment: It's an iOS bug...

Comment: It is a bug in iOS 12.1. They will fix in the next release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Abhijit,

To bringing this issue into our notice.

Yes, UITababarController image is fluctuating when you come back to parent view controller.

You can fix it by using below line of code

```
[self.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Or simply set the `isTranslucent = false` in UITabBarController

**Happy to help you :)**